# Heroku app crashing after deployment

Tags: heroku, deployment

My `Heroku` app seems to always crash after deployment.

The errors on `Heroku` logs are:

> 2015-07-21T13:28:08.173666+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
>       desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=calm-hamlet-
>       5165.herokuapp.com request_id=93f36ad5-f9c2-42b2-a662-9f730d1228ab
>       fwd="197.253.32.226" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

and

> 2015-07-21T13:29:28.127452+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 
>       desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/api/v1/sessions" 
>       host=calm-hamlet-5165.herokuapp.com request_id=69711e3a-913e-45ed-
>       b4bf-82baaa164edf fwd="197.253.32.226" dyno= connect= service= 
>       status=503 bytes=

What could be causing this error?

Comment: check this answer on a similair question: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/71741446/16949497](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71741446/16949497)

Answer (score 0):

Probably is a port definition problem. Heroku will assign a port on which the application will run, regardless of you defining it. You should replace that hardcoded port for something like this.

```
    var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
```

Hopefully that fix the problem